# Understanding the input of the lazy quicksort presented in The Joy of Clojure

Tags: algorithm, clojure

I copied the lazy quicksort implementation from The Joy of Clojure
and added two println statements after the loop, to better understand how the input works (see implementation at the bottom).

When running `(qsort [2 1 4 3])` I get this output:

```
Work: = ([2 1 4 3]) =
Part: = [2 1 4 3] & nil =
=pivot:  2 =
Work: = ([2 1 4 3]) =
Part: = (1) & (2 (4 3)) =
[...]
```

as expected. What I don't understand is the the structure of Work. How can `Work` just be a list containing a vector and `part & parts` be `(1) & (2 (4 3))`. Should `Work` not have the following structure `[(1) (2 (4 3))]`?

---

The quicksort implementation for completeness:

```
(defn sort-parts
  "Lazy, tail-recursive, incremental quicksort. Works against and
creates partitions based on the pivot, defined as 'work'."
  [work]
  (lazy-seq
   (loop [[part & parts] work]
     (println "Work: =" work "=")
     (println "Part: =" part "&" parts "=")
     (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
       (do (println "=pivot: " pivot "=")
           (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
             (recur (list*
                     (filter smaller? xs)
                     pivot
                     (remove smaller? xs)
                     parts))))
       (when-let [[x & parts] parts]
         (println "output")
         (cons x (sort-parts parts)))))))

(defn qsort [xs]
  (sort-parts (list xs)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
(println "Work: =" work "=")
```

doesn't print the `work` you see in the `loop` form.

It prints the outer `work` bound in `sort-parts` argument list. This changes only when `sort-parts` is called.

To get the expected result, change:

```
 (loop [[part & parts] work]
```

to

```
 (loop [[part & parts :as work] work]
```

That way you bind work to the whole loop argument list.

Comment: I'm still looking in source for explanation why exactly that happens. I'll update the answer if I find something.

Comment: I think it makes sense, loop brings it's binding form and only locals in the binding form get bound. `work` in this case is not part of the binding, so no local in the context of loop is created. Therefore the local `work` from the clojure defined by sort-parts is returned.

Comment: You're right. I don't know why suddenly i thought that making the expression side of the binding form available as binding was a good idea ;)

Comment: `loop` just looks too much like a function in this example :-).